# How do I extract only the data before a pattern string

Tags: sql, sql-server, patindex

How do I extract only the string after `CX_EduDegree=???????` and replace the `%20` with spaces. The data is separated by spaces, and is never in the same position.

I have tried to use the patindex with substring and replace.  But I have had no success.

```sql
select top 5 clientid, extFields
from tblSYS_Clients
where ExtFields like '%CX_Edu%'
and ClientID in ('1633496','1633692','1453977','1657410','1584563','1655341','1632686','1352611','1484271','1361354')
```

```
clientid    extFields
1352611 CX_CurrentJobStartDate=01/20/2001  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Rhonda%20Kaiser  CX_EduDegree=BS%20in%20Nursing  CX_SupervisorPhone=970-495-8100
1361354 CX_CurrentJobStartDate=06/20/1997  CX_CurrentJobHours=30  CX_SupervisorName=Georgia%20Chapin  CX_SupervisorPhone=702-616-5632  CX_EduDegree=MS/MA%20%20in%20Nursing
1453977 CX_CurrentJobStartDate=08/20/1990  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Jan%20Rasco  CX_SupervisorPhone=281-631-8789  CX_EduDegree=Diploma
1484271 CX_CurrentJobStartDate=01/01/2011  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Kay%20Hix  CX_SupervisorPhone=317-329-7209  CX_EduDegree=AD%20in%20Nursing
1584563 CX_CurrentJobStartDate=11/26/2006  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=PHILLIP%20MOISUK  CX_SupervisorPhone=916-453-4545  CX_EduDegree=BS%20in%20Nursing
```

Results I want to see:

```
1633496 BS in Nursing 
1633692 BS in Nursing 
1453977 Diploma 
1657410 AD in Nursing 
1584563 BS in Nursing 
1655341 AD in Nursing 
1632686 BS in Nursing 
1352611 BS in Nursing 
1484271 AD in Nursing 
1361354 MS/MA in Nursing
```

Comment: are you using sql server?

Comment: will `CX_EduDegree=..` always be at the end of the string?

Comment: I am using sql server.  No, the string CX_EduDegree=  is never in the same place and could be at the beginning, middle, or the end.   Its storing data from user entry, and if they don't enter something it falls earlier or later, and sometimes isn't even included.

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation is a bit cumbersome in SQL Server.  I like to do it using `outer apply`:

```
select c.clientid, c.extFields, x2.x2
from tblSYS_Clients c outer apply
     (select stuff(c.ExtFields, 1, charindex('CX_edu', c.ExtFields), '') as x1
     ) x outer apply
     (select replace(left(x.x1, charindex(' ', x1)), '%20', ' ') as x2
     ) x2
where c.ExtFields like '%CX_Edu%' and
      c.ClientID in ('1633496', '1633692', '1453977', '1657410', '1584563', '1655341', '1632686', '1352611', '1484271', '1361354') ;
```

Note:  I *think* the above will work.  SQL Server does not guarantee that the `where` is processed before the `outer apply` subqueries.  In practice, I think it does, so the filtering is done guaranteeing that the substring is in `ExtFields`.  If not, this can readily be fixed using `case`, but that complicates the answer a bit.

Comment: received errors using this code on sql server...    Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The stuff function requires 4 argument(s).
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'x2'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `charindex`,`reverse` and `substring`. This will work if `CX_EduDegree=` always appears towards the end of the string.

[Demo with sample data](http://rextester.com/LNKV96161)

```
select clientid,
substring(
          extfields
          ,charindex('CX_EduDegree=',extFields)+len('CX_EduDegree=')
          ,charindex(' ',extFields)
         ) as extfield
from tblSYS_Clients
where ExtFields like '%CX_Edu%'
and ClientID in ('1633496','1633692','1453977','1657410','1584563','1655341','1632686','1352611','1484271','1361354')
```

Comment: when i run this chunk of code, the extfield column is blank for everything

Comment: as mentioned,this will only work if CX_EduDegree= is always at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this construction:

```
select clientid, replace(SUBSTRING(extFields,
   PATINDEX('%CX_EduDegree=%',extFields)+13,
      charindex(' ', extFields+' ',
          PATINDEX('%CX_EduDegree=%',extFields)) - 
             PATINDEX('%CX_EduDegree=%',extFields) - 13),'%20',' ') ex 
from  
(values 
(1352611, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=01/20/2001  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Rhonda%20Kaiser  CX_EduDegree=BS%20in%20Nursing  CX_SupervisorPhone=970-495-8100'), 
(1361354, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=06/20/1997  CX_CurrentJobHours=30  CX_SupervisorName=Georgia%20Chapin  CX_SupervisorPhone=702-616-5632  CX_EduDegree=MS/MA%20%20in%20Nursing'), 
(1453977, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=08/20/1990  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Jan%20Rasco  CX_SupervisorPhone=281-631-8789  CX_EduDegree=Diploma'), 
(1484271, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=01/01/2011  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Kay%20Hix  CX_SupervisorPhone=317-329-7209  CX_EduDegree=AD%20in%20Nursing'), 
(1584563, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=11/26/2006  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=PHILLIP%20MOISUK  CX_SupervisorPhone=916-453-4545  CX_EduDegree=BS%20in%20Nursing') 
) t(clientid,    extFields)
```

Results:

```
clientid    ex
1352611 BS in Nursing
1361354 MS/MA  in Nursing
1453977 Diploma
1484271 AD in Nursing
1584563 BS in Nursing
```

Some comments inside the code for better understanding. As you see `charindex` works too. Results are the same.

```
select clientid, 
replace(
SUBSTRING(extFields,--string to work with
   charindex('CX_EduDegree=',extFields)+13, --start position; 13 is length of CX_EduDegree=
      charindex(' ', extFields+' ', --searching end position +' ' to make sure that space exists
          charindex('CX_EduDegree=',extFields) -- start searching ' ' after this position
          ) --end position found
             - charindex('CX_EduDegree=',extFields) - 13) -- calculate length
             ,'%20',' ') ex --final touch - remove ugly %20 
from  
(values 
(1352611, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=01/20/2001  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Rhonda%20Kaiser  CX_EduDegree=BS%20in%20Nursing  CX_SupervisorPhone=970-495-8100'), 
(1361354, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=06/20/1997  CX_CurrentJobHours=30  CX_SupervisorName=Georgia%20Chapin  CX_SupervisorPhone=702-616-5632  CX_EduDegree=MS/MA%20%20in%20Nursing'), 
(1453977, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=08/20/1990  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Jan%20Rasco  CX_SupervisorPhone=281-631-8789  CX_EduDegree=Diploma'), 
(1484271, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=01/01/2011  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=Kay%20Hix  CX_SupervisorPhone=317-329-7209  CX_EduDegree=AD%20in%20Nursing'), 
(1584563, 'CX_CurrentJobStartDate=11/26/2006  CX_CurrentJobHours=40  CX_SupervisorName=PHILLIP%20MOISUK  CX_SupervisorPhone=916-453-4545  CX_EduDegree=BS%20in%20Nursing') 
) t(clientid,    extFields)
```

Do you find this solution acceptable?

Comment: This is really close to what I need.  I am still getting some results though that have more after the info I want....  1352611 BS in Nursing  CX_SupervisorPhone=970-495-8100

Comment: The parts of data that occur after and  that I want to strip will always begin with CX_[A-Z]

Comment: Look at my code. I specially addressed this issue. `PATINDEX('%CX_EduDegree=%',extFields)) - 
             PATINDEX('%CX_EduDegree=%',extFields) - 13)` as `substring length. Results are real from the query.

Comment: 1339940 BS in Nursing
1352557 MS/MA  in Nursing
1352566 MS/MA  in Nursing
1352579 Diploma
1352582 BS in Nursing
1352590 Diploma
1352594 BS in Nursing
1352596 BS in Nursing
1352603 AD in Nursing
1352606 MS/MA  in Nursing
1352611 BS in Nursing  CX_SupervisorPhone=970-495-8100
1352618 AD in Nursing
1352627 AD in Nursing
1352630 BS/BA Other Field
1352631 BS in Nursing
1352638 BS in Nursing
1352640 AD in Nursing
1352647 Diploma
1352660 BS in Nursing
1352661 BS in Nursing
1352664 AD in Nursing
1352672 MS/MA  in Nursing
1352676 MS/MA  in Nursing
1352677 MS/MA  in Nursing

Comment: The results are from the query i just ran.   it only leaves trailing info when there is what looks like a space and another entry with CX_Supervisor or CX_VOL, or the next field being stored...

Comment: I am thinking i can make another pass at the update for those???  update the ones that work, and fix the rest?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Alex, I am definitely much closer than i was.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using XML datatype

```
SELECT  clientid,
        REPLACE(t.cx.value('(r/@CX_EduDegree)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),'%20',' ') AS degree
FROM    (
    SELECT  clientid, 
            CAST('<r ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(extFields,'=','="') , '  ','"/><r ') + '"></r>') AS XML) cx
    FROM    tblSYS_Clients
    WHERE   clientid in ('1633496','1633692','1453977','1657410','1584563','1655341','1632686','1352611','1484271','1361354') 
) t
```

xml is a pretty slow though compared to string manipulation queries.

another thing you can do is use a string splitter like one of the ones [**HERE**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

here is an example using Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K function.

```
SELECT  t1.clientid,
        REPLACE(t2.Item,'CX_EduDegree=','')
FROM    tblSYS_Clients t1
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT REPLACE(t.Item, '%20', ' ') Item 
            FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t1.extFields, '  ') t 
            WHERE t.Item LIKE 'CX_EduDegree%' 
        ) t2
WHERE   clientid in ('1633496','1633692','1453977','1657410','1584563','1655341','1632686','1352611','1484271','1361354')
```

still not as fast as some of the others here, but might be easier to understand or allow you to get other fields easier.

Comment: not able to run the first block of code in MS SQL Server...   Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Lee oh yeah.. that's sql 2012 stuff.. ill just replace with `+`